# Recursive method with FTPClient and Hibernate, Speed Optimization

Tags: java, hibernate, ftp-client

I am a novice using FTPClient (org.apache.commons.net.ftp) and Hibernate 4, and I have basic questions to optimize speed of the application.

What I am trying to achieve are:

(1) Connect to a FTP server and browse through all directories and find all files. To browse each and every folder, I use a recursive method that checks whether the file(FTPFile) is a file or directory.

(2) Every time it finds a file (not folder), it will create an entity and insert it to the database via using Hibernate.

The problem is that it is taking so long time to check all the files and insert into the databases.. There are about 7000 files (each file is located under unique directory) and it takes approximately 1 hour on average, which I believe is very slow. In addition, just to check if there are any updates on the FTP server, it takes about 58 minutes on average...

Here is the recursive method to do the two tasks mentioned above:

```
public void recursiveMethod(String directory){
    Transaction tx = null;
    FTPFile[] files = null;

    try {

        ftpObj.changeWorkingDirectory(directory);

        files = ftpObj.listFiles();
        assertNotNull(files);

        for(FTPFile file: files){
            String tempFileName = file.getName();

            if(file.isFile() && !file.isDirectory() && !tempFileName.matches(Constants.regexNotMatchFile) && tempFileName.matches(Constants.regexMatchFile)){
                 System.out.println("called: " + tempFileName);

                 //check if the entity exists in DB based on the ID, where ID is the filename
                 if(session.get(Package.class, tempFileName) != null){
                     //if exists, continue looping
                     continue;
                 }

                 try{
                    tx = session.beginTransaction();
                    assertNotNull(tx);

                    //POJO
                    Package p = new Package();
                    p.setName(tempFileName);
                    p.setDate(file.getTimestamp().getTime());
                    p.setDirectory(directory.replace(baseDir, ""));
                    p.setSize((long)(file.getSize());

                    session.save(p);
                    tx.commit();

                }catch(Exception e){
                    if(tx != null){
                        //rollback db to previous state
                        tx.rollback();
                    }
                    System.err.println("transaction creation error: "+ e);
                }

                System.out.println("File Name: " + tempFileName + " Timestamp: "+file.getTimestamp().getTime());

             }else{

                if(file.isDirectory() && !tempFileName.matches(Constants.regexNotMatchFile) && !tempFileName.matches(currentKeyValue)){
                    String newDir = directory + "/" +tempFileName;

                    try {
                        ftpObj.changeWorkingDirectory(newDir);
                        System.out.println("called into dir: " + newDir);
                        dbTransaction(newDir);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }

             }
        }

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }       

}
```

What would be the best way to improve speed and efficiency? 
Should I first store found files to an array and then commit them altogether at the end?

Comment: Couldn't you do the directories in parallel?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with it. Could you inform me how to achieve it?

Comment: What have you tried to speed things up? Have you profiled your code to see where you are spending the most time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very unlikely that the database insert is that slow (it could be, but seems unlikely), more likely the FTP connection is a high-latency connection.  The best way to speed this up is to create a [consumer/producer pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/concurrency-pattern-producer), and specify a number of consumers to have simultaneous ftp connections.

Comment: I was able to improve speed by 20 minutes. It takes about 40 minutes now :) I think it is the FTP connection that hinders performance as the FTP server is in another country :/ Anyways thanks!